# GoogleMock mocking non-virtual functions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c++11, googlemock

We're writing unit tests for an existing code base. We're using Google Test/Google Mock for the tests, C++11 and Eclipse CDT with the gcc compiler.

One of our classes aggregates a Boost Socket. It used it as an instance, but luckily we can modify the existing code base, and I changed it to a pointer and injected the socket as a dependency. So I went about mocking the calls to the socket, but there's a problem: the Boost functions are non-virtual.

I found documentation showing how to mock non-virtual functions using *[hi-perf dependency injection](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods)*. Trying to implement it as shown, though, has been unsuccessful. For example, the doc says to "templatize your code". So for our class that uses the boost socket, I followed their example. I inserted:

```
template <class boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>
```

That is supposed to let us insert our mock class instead of the concrete Boost class. I tried it before the class and separately just before the constructor that accepts the socket, in the header and the implementation file. In each place, I just get tons of errors, most of which are along the lines of "no matching function call for " the constructor call.

Clearly, I'm doing something wrong. Does anyone know of a complete example somewhere?

**Update:**
Per request, here is what we currently have:

GoogleMock mocking non-virtual functions

```
class PIngester : public IPIngester{
public:
    // this is the method that takes the socket. It is the constructor, and the socket
    // is a default parameter so the existing code will still work. We added the socket 
    // as a parameter specifically for unit testing. If no socket is provided, the 
    // constructor creates one. It only will ever create a concrete Boost
    // Socket, not a mock one.
    PIngester(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, Band band,
              std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> socket = std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(nullptr));
    ...
```

**Update 2**

I defined a generic class type for the template, but that breaks the existing code. Here is my current version:

```
class PIngester : public IPIngester{
public:
    template <class Socket>
    PIngester(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, Band band,
              std::unique_ptr<Socket> socket = std::unique_ptr<Socket>(nullptr));
    ...
```

I think it might be barfing on the default parameter, but I can't be sure. The error messages aren't very helpful:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘foonamespace::PIngester::PIngester(boost::asio::io_service&, foonamespace::Band&)’                                     
          new PIngester(ioService, band));
```

This error message is from existing code; it doesn't seem to recognize the default parameter.

**Update 3**

I've abandoned this approach and decided to write a Boost Socket Wrapper instead. The wrapper will hold the actual Socket instance, and its methods will be direct pass-throughs to the actual Socket. The wrapper's functions will be virtual, and my mock object will inherit from the wrapper. Then my mock object will mock the wrapper's virtual functions.

Comment: Could you show us how you've set it up so far? To me, `template <class boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>` seems like you're defining a template parameter as part of a function definition (in which case you'd define a generic class name instead of `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket`). If you're trying to pass in a template parameter according to the Google Mock documentation, I'd expect to see something like `TestFunction<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>()` instead.

Comment: Okay, added. If I understand correctly, I only need to templatize it if I need a way to use the concrete class in production code and my mock class in tests? I don't think this will be a problem, since I only instantiate the concrete class in the constructor when a socket isn't passed in, which the production code already does. I'll always pass in a mock in tests.

Answer (score 2):

The issue, as you've noticed, is that the compiler cannot deduce whatever type `Socket` is meant to represent here:

```
class PIngester : public IPIngester{
public:
    template <class Socket>
    PIngester(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, Band band,
              std::unique_ptr<Socket> socket = std::unique_ptr<Socket>(nullptr));
    ...
```

If you try to construct an object of this class without specifying the third argument (as in `new PIngester(ioService, band)`), what would `Socket` be exactly?

Now, there's no way to explicitly specify any template parameter when calling the constructor, so you can't do something like `new PIngester<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(ioService, band)` if the constructor is templatized.

---

Here are a couple ways (out of potentially many) to work around this:

1. You could templatize the `PIngester` class itself:

   ```
   template <class Socket>
   class PIngester : public IPIngester{
   public:
       PIngester(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, Band band,
                 std::unique_ptr<Socket> socket = std::unique_ptr<Socket>(nullptr));
       ...
   ```

   Then calling `new PIngester<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>(ioService, band)` (or your mock class in place of `boost::asio::ip::udp::socket`) would work.
2. You could define a default template parameter:

   ```
   class PIngester : public IPIngester{
   public:
       template <class Socket = boost::asio::ip::udp::socket>
       PIngester(boost::asio::io_service& ioService, Band band,
                 std::unique_ptr<Socket> socket = std::unique_ptr<Socket>(nullptr));
       ...
   ```

   Then `PIngester(ioService, band)` would always use this default Boost class, and you'd need to explicitly pass in some `socket` that represents a unique pointer to your mock class if you want to use this in tests.

Comment: These are great suggestions, thanks! I'll give them a shot.

Comment: I tried this, but like a hydra, I cut off one head, and two more appear. Now gcc says that I can't have a template type as member data. It's okay; I'm going to write a Boost Socket wrapper that has virtual functions that are direct pass-thrus to an actual Boost Socket. My mock object will inherit from the wrapper, and mock its virtual functions.

Comment: Not a bad idea; that's a good approach to handle 3rd party classes.